# What is an efficient way to get a count of objects grouped by a field in Django?

Tags: sql, django, python-2.7

I'm working on a large Django app, specifically part of it that sends out many emails and then collects information on them.  I have two models that relate to each other through a third model:

SendEvent is a model for capturing when I successfully send any number of emails - it records some data that isn't relevant to the problem.

SentEmail is the intermediary table.  It contains a foreign key reference to a SendEvent, named sendevent, and some other extra information.

I then have a model called EmailEvents, which is listening for certain webhooks from the third party mailer application I'm using, and stores information about what recipients are doing with my emails.  This model contains a foreign key reference to a SentEmail object.  There are several EmailEvents that will be associated with a single SentEmail - the most relevant are 'sent' and 'opened' (when an email is sent, a sent event is generated and recorded in the EmailEvents table, and associated via a unique id string with the SentEmail.  Similar for the open event, except it is generated when an email is opened by the recipient, obviously).  The type of event is stored as a string in a field called event.

I'm attempting to write a query that, given a SendEvent, will give me a count of the different types of associated EmailEvents.

So far, I have the following worked out (send_event is the variable containing the reference to the relevant SendEvent):

```
email_events = EmailEvents.objects.filter(sent_mail__sendevent = sent_event)
```

I believe this will fetch all of the correct EmailEvent objects (those that are associated with SentEmails that are associated with a given SendEvent).  I can then add a .count() to the end of that and get a count of all the EmailEvents.  What I really want, though, is to split this up into the different types of EmailEvents.  I could do this manually, by looping through the QuerySet, but I anticipate the EmailEvents table becoming quite large, so I would very much prefer to have the ORM do this lifting for me instead.  How can I group these by event?

Can I do

```
EmailEvents.objects.filter(sent_mail__sendevent = sent_event).annotate(Count('event'))
```

Is that the best way?  Will that work at all?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated - I'm a little new to working with massive amounts of data in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the objects.values together with annotate.  here is a sample model + test.

first in your models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and then in tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db.models import Count
from foo.models import Foo

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_group_query(self):
        options = ('created', 'deleted', 'updated')
        for i in range(32):
            Foo.objects.create(
                action_type=options[i%3]
                )
        results = Foo.objects.values('action_type').annotate(Count('action_type'))
        print results
```

produces an array with the following

```
{'action_type__count': 11, 'action_type': u'created'}, 
{'action_type__count': 11, 'action_type': u'deleted'}, 
{'action_type__count': 10, 'action_type': u'updated'}
```

Comment: More information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the Django ORM has an easy way to do what you need, but you can always drop to raw SQL - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/

The raw SQL would be something like the following (I am taking wild guesses with what your tables would be called, but the query is essentially like the following):

`select count(distinct(e.event)) from EmailEvents as e, SentEvent where EmailEvent.id = SentEvent.id`

Comment: Great, thank you.  I was looking for a way to do it without having to drop out of Django's abstraction, but this is a helpful back up.  And it worked, so that's a step above what I had.